# Plotly Choropleth figure with callbacks not loading in dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, choropleth

I tried looking for a pre-existing answer to this question, but unfortunately, I can't seem to locate one that matches my situation. If there is one, please point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Anyway, on to my question!

My work uses ploty-dash for dashboards and I was trying to make what I considered a basic choropleth map that shows which states/counties are grouped into different versions of our models. This is principally for internal use to help product managers and sales teams understand which models may be causing problems for a region and help identify where fixes need to be made.

To do this, I constructed a .parquet file that contains a column with county FIPS numbers ('counties'), a column with the associated model's version name ('version'), and the crop type that is being modeled with that model ('crop_type'). I wanted to use callbacks to filter through the crops, so I added a dropdown menu called "crop_drop" with the id='crop_dropdown'.

However, launching the dashboard yields no map (see below). This is frustrating because I know the choropleth map function I wrote works in Jupyter notebook and I can't see any reason it shouldn't work in this situation. I've had two senior coworkers look at this issue already and they can't see anything wrong with the code as-written, so I'm left to floundering for a bit. If anyone could look over my code and let me know what it is I'm missing, I'd appreciate it.

## Map generated in Jupyter notebook:

[image: US County Choropleth map colored by model version]

## Code Section

### app.py

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

### model_versions_dashboard2.py

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from app import app
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from model_versions_layout import make_layout
from urllib.request import urlopen

app.layout = make_layout()
```

### model_versions_layout.py

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from app import app
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html
from dash.html import Div
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import json



def make_layout():
    rows = dbc.Container(
        [
            dbc.Col(
                [
                    dbc.Row(header()),
                    dbc.Row(sidebar())    
                ], width = "auto"
                   ),
            dbc.Col(
                [
                    dbc.Row(dcc.Graph(figure="version_plot"))    
                ], width = "auto"
            )
        ],
        fluid=True
    )
    return rows

def header():

    header = [
        html.H1("Model Versions"),
    ]
    return header


def sidebar():
    sidebar = [
        Div(html.H3("Input arguments")),
        crop_drop(),
    ]
    return sidebar

def crop_drop():
    crop_drop = Div(
        [
            html.H5("Crop"),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="crop_dropdown",
                options=[
                     {"label": crop, "value": file}
                     for crop, file in data_files.items()
                 ],
                 value=list(data_files.values())[0],
                    {"label":"Corn","value":"corn"},
                    {"label":"Cotton","value":"cotton_upland"},
                    {"label":"Soybeans","value":"soybeans"},
                    {"label":"Spring Wheat","value":"spring_wheat"},
                    {"label":"Winter Wheat","value":"winter_wheat"},
                ],
                value="corn",
            ),
        ],
        style={"width": "90%", "margin-top": "25px", "margin-bottom": "25px"},
    )
    return crop_drop


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="version_plot", component_property="figure"),
    [
        Input(component_id="crop_dropdown", component_property="value"),
    ],
)
def plot_map(crop_dropdown):
    with open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
        counties = json.load(response)
    all_versions = pd.read_parquet(f"s3://{FILE_PATH}/helper_data/dashboard_files/model_versions/2022/model_versions_all_crops.parquet")
    crop_versions = all_versions[all_versions.crop_type==crop_dropdown]
    fig = px.choropleth(crop_versions, geojson=counties, 
                        locations='counties', 
                        color='version', 
                        scope="usa",
                       )
    return fig
```

## Dashboard Output

[image]